# Подключение шаблона к конкретной странице Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь подключить к странице с именем http://localhost/site/page-contacts/ новый шаблон. Для этого прописал в файле `page-contacts.php` следующий код

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"><br>
            <?php
                $post = get_post($post_id = 7); // Записываем все данные записи 7 в объект $post
                echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'</p>'; // Выводим контент записи;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Но выводит только содержимое футера и хидера, что нужно добавить, чтобы вывести запись с таким айди? (Проверил, в базе есть запись с таким айди)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><br>
        <?php
            $post = get_post(7); // Просто 7
            echo wpautop($post->post_content); // Позвольте Wordpress самому разобраться с форматированием текста, с помощью функции wpautop
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Создаете файл template-vashallias.php и вот его содержимое:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Шаблон контактов
 */
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><br>
        <?php
            $post = get_post($post_id = 7); // Записываем все данные записи 7 в объект $post
            echo '<p>'.$post->post_content.'</p>'; // Выводим контент записи;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Сделав это вы увидите внутри страницы чекбокс, который выведет вашу страницу в запрограммированном вами формате с названием "Шаблон контактов".